# C struct sizes inconsistence

Tags: c++, c, struct, sizeof

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find the size of a struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143025/how-do-i-find-the-size-of-a-struct)
>   [Struct varies in memory size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800884/struct-varies-in-memory-size)

I am using following struct for network communication, It creates lots of unnecessary bytes in between.

It gives different size than expected 8 Bytes.

```
struct HttpPacket {
  unsigned char x1;
  union {
        struct {
           unsigned char  len;
           unsigned short host;
           unsigned char content[4];
        } packet;
        unsigned char bytes[7];
        unsigned long num;
    }
```

And Following gives different size even though that I am removing a field from a union

```
struct HttpPacket {
             unsigned char x1;
             union {
            struct {
               unsigned char  len;
               unsigned short host;
               unsigned char content[4];
            } packet;
            unsigned long num;
        }
```

---

Also, A more clear example

```
struct {
               unsigned char  len;
               unsigned short host;
               unsigned char content[4];
            } packet;
```

And it gives a size of 8, instead of 7. 
And I add one more field, It still gives the same size

```
struct {
               unsigned char  EXTRAADDEDFIELD;
               unsigned char  len;
               unsigned short host;
               unsigned char content[4];
            } packet;
```

---

**Can someone please help on resolving this issue ?**

UPDATE: I need the format to hold while transmitting the packet, So I want to skip these paddings

Comment: I need the format to hold while transmitting the packet, So I want to skip these paddings

Comment: Need this on XCode 4 LLVM Compiler

Comment: But, I need the solution for XCode 4 new LLVM Compiler.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ever heard of [alignment and padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment)?

Basically, to ensure fast access, certain types have to be on certain bounds of memory addresses.
**This is called alignment.**

To achieve that, the compiler is allowed to insert bytes into your data structure to achieve that alignment.
**This is called padding.**

Answer (score 10):

C makes no guarantees on the size of a `struct`.  The compiler is allowed to line up the members however it wants. Usually, as in this case, it will make the size word-aligned since that's fastest on most machines.

Comment: Some compiles support pragmas to disable padding. This is most often seen in embeded development but I don't know if it is restricted to that.

Comment: +1 for the first polite response.

Comment: Some extra reading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof#Structure_padding

Answer (score 2):

By default, structure fields are aligned on natural boundaries.  For example, a 4-byte field will start on a 4-byte boundary.  The compiler inserts pad bytes to achieve this.  You can avoid the padding by using #pragma pack(0) or other similar compiler directives

Comment: How to do that on LLVM XCode 4 compiler

Answer (score 0):

If you have a C99 compiler and can use the "new" fixed-width types: make an array of `uint8_t` and do the separation in members yourself.

```
uint8_t data[8];

x1 = data[0];
len = data[1];
host = data[2] * 256 + data[3]; /* big endian */
content[0] = data[4];
content[1] = data[5];
content[2] = data[6];
content[3] = data[7];

/* ... */
```

You can follow the same procedure in C89 if you can rely on `CHAR_BIT` being 8.