# Size of Structs in Objective-C and C++

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c, struct

I am converting some Objective-C++ code into plain Objective-C and I am having some trouble with structs.  For both languages, I have the struct declared in the .h file like this.

```
struct BasicNIDSHeader {
    short messageCode;
    short messageDate;
    int messageTime;
    int messageLength;
    short sourceID;
    short destID;
    short numberOfBlocks;
};
```

In C++, the struct is being declared like

```
BasicNIDSHeader header;
```

and in Objective-C I do this

```
struct BasicNIDSHeader header;
```

The code for using them is actually the same in both languages.

```
memset(&header, 0, sizeof(header));
[[fileHandle readDataOfLength:sizeof(header)] getBytes:&header];
```

where fileHandle is a NSFileHandle.

The problem is than in the original C++ code, sizeof(header) = 18. When using Objective-C,  sizeof(header) = 20.

Any ideas why this is happening or how to fix it?  The code is dependent on the size being like it is in C++.  I can just hardcode it, but would like to have a better understanding of why it is happening.  Plus I hate hardcoding constants.

Thanks!

Comment: You could use a typedef and then you don't need to modify all your declarations.

Comment: You could see the place where there's change by printing `&header`, `&header.messageCode`, `&header.messageDate`, etc. in both languages, and see if there is a gap, or there's padding at the end.

Comment: Are you using C++ at all, or just Objective-C++ (in addition to Objective-C)?  The code you showed, which is "the same in both languages", certainly isn't C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you depend on the internal memory structure of your `struct`s - you should disable padding. This is called "packed", and different compilers have different ways of signalling it.

In GCC you do this with the `__attribute__` keyword. Details [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3.6/gcc/Type-Attributes.html).

Comment: Adding __attribute__((packed)) to the .h file did it. Works in LLVM too. Thanks!

Comment: Note that [`__attribute__((packed))` isn't necessarily safe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8568432/is-gccs-attribute-packed-pragma-pack-unsafe).

Comment: Just Objective-C++ (in response to your other question). And how so?

Comment: @Ross - it can cause alignment issues on some systems.

Comment: @RossKimes: Follow the link for the details.

Answer (score 0):

I can only speak for C++. In C++ there is an implementation specific feature which aligns the data on specific addresses, so that data can be processed efficently.

In MS Visual C++ you can enforce byte alignment with a pragma:

```
#pragma pack(1)
```