# Why texture data can't show?

Tags: ios, swift, opengl-es, glkit

I try to use `GLKit` to show a cube. However some trouble confused me. I can't load my texture. The code likes below:

```
import UIKit
import OpenGLES
import GLKit

struct CubeVertex {
    var positionCoord: GLKVector3 
    var textureCoord: GLKVector2 
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var glkView: GLKView = {
        let glkView = GLKView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 200, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width))
        glkView.backgroundColor = .purple
        //使用深度缓存
        glkView.drawableDepthFormat = GLKViewDrawableDepthFormat.format24
        glkView.delegate = self
        view.addSubview(glkView)
        return glkView
    }()

    lazy var baseEffect: GLKBaseEffect = {
        let baseEffect = GLKBaseEffect()
        return baseEffect
    }()

    //顶点数
    let kCoordCount = 36

    lazy var vertices: UnsafeMutablePointer<CubeVertex> = {
        let verticesSize = MemoryLayout<CubeVertex>.size * kCoordCount
        let vertices = UnsafeMutablePointer<CubeVertex>.allocate(capacity: verticesSize)
        return vertices
    }()

    lazy var displayLink: CADisplayLink = {
        let displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(glkViewDisplay))
        return displayLink
    }()

    var angle = 0
    var vertexBuffer = GLuint()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupContext()
        setupEffect()
        setupVertexData()
        addDisplayLink()
    }


    private func setupContext() {
        if let context = EAGLContext(api: EAGLRenderingAPI.openGLES3) {
            EAGLContext.setCurrent(context)
            glkView.context = context
        }
    }

    private func setupEffect() {

        guard  let imagePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "me", ofType: "png", inDirectory: nil),
                   let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath)?.cgImage
            else { return  }


        let options = [GLKTextureLoaderOriginBottomLeft : NSNumber(value: true)]
        let textureInfo = try? GLKTextureLoader.texture(with: image, options: options)
        if let textureInfo = textureInfo, let target = GLKTextureTarget(rawValue: textureInfo.target) {
            baseEffect.texture2d0.name = textureInfo.name
            baseEffect.texture2d0.target = target
        }

    }

    private func setupVertexData() {
        // front
        self.vertices[0] = CubeVertex(positionCoord: GLKVector3(v: (-0.5, 0.5, 0.5)), textureCoord: GLKVector2(v: (0, 1)))
        self.vertices[1] = CubeVertex(positionCoord: GLKVector3(v: (-0.5, -0.5, 0.5)), textureCoord: GLKVector2(v: (0, 0)))
        self.vertices[2] = CubeVertex(positionCoord: GLKVector3(v: (0.5, 0.5, 0.5)), textureCoord: GLKVector2(v: (1, 1)))

        self.vertices[3] = CubeVertex(positionCoord: GLKVector3(v: (-0.5, -0.5, 0.5)), textureCoord: GLKVector2(v: (0, 0)))
        self.vertices[4] = CubeVertex(positionCoord: GLKVector3(v: (0.5, 0.5, 0.5)), textureCoord: GLKVector2(v: (1, 1)))
        self.vertices[5] = CubeVertex(positionCoord: GLKVector3(v: (0.5, -0.5, 0.5)), textureCoord: GLKVector2(v: (1, 0)))

        // above
        self.vertices[6] = CubeVertex(positionCoord: GLKVector3(v: (0.5, 0.5, 0.5)), textureCoord: GLKVector2(v: (1, 1)))
        self.vertices[7] = CubeVertex(positionCoord: GLKVector3(v: (-0.5, 0.5, 0.5)), textureCoord: GLKVector2(v: (0, 1)))
        self.vertices[8] = CubeVertex(positionCoord: GLKVector3(v: (0.5, 0.5, -0.5)), textureCoord: GLKVector2(v: (1, 0)))

        self.vertices[9] = CubeVertex(positionCoord: GLKVector3(v: (-0.5, 0.5, 0.5)), textureCoord: GLKVector2(v: (0, 1)))
        self.vertices[10] = CubeVertex(positionCoord: GLKVector3(v: (0.5, 0.5, -0.5)), textureCoord: GLKVector2(v: (1, 0)))
        self.vertices[11] = CubeVertex(positionCoord: GLKVector3(v: (-0.5, 0.5, -0.5)), textureCoord: GLKVector2(v: (0, 0)))

        // below
        self.vertices[12] = CubeVertex(positionCoord: GLKVector3(v: (0.5, -0.5, 0.5)), textureCoord: GLKVector2(v: (1, 1)))
        self.vertices[13] = CubeVertex(positionCoord: GLKVector3(v: (-0.5, -0.5, 0.5)), textureCoord: GLKVector2(v: (0, 1)))
        self.vertices[14] = CubeVertex(positionCoord: GLKVector3(v: (0.5, -0.5, -0.5)), textureCoord: GLKVector2(v: (1, 0)))

        self.vertices[15] = CubeVertex(positionCoord: GLKVector3(v: (-0.5, -0.5, 0.5)), textureCoord: GLKVector2(v: (0, 1)))
        self.vertices[16] = CubeVertex(positionCoord: GLKVector3(v: (0.5, -0.5, -0.5)), textureCoord: GLKVector2(v: (1, 0)))
        self.vertices[17] = CubeVertex(positionCoord: GLKVector3(v: (-0.5, -0.5, -0.5)), textureCoord: GLKVector2(v: (0, 0)))

        // left
        self.vertices[18] = CubeVertex(positionCoord: GLKVector3(v: (-0.5, 0.5, 0.5)), textureCoord: GLKVector2(v: (1, 1)))
        self.vertices[19] = CubeVertex(positionCoord: GLKVector3(v: (-0.5, -0.5, 0.5)), textureCoord: GLKVector2(v: (0, 1)))
        self.vertices[20] = CubeVertex(positionCoord: GLKVector3(v: (-0.5, 0.5, -0.5)), textureCoord: GLKVector2(v: (1, 0)))

        self.vertices[21] = CubeVertex(positionCoord: GLKVector3(v: (-0.5, -0.5, 0.5)), textureCoord: GLKVector2(v: (0, 1)))
        self.vertices[22] = CubeVertex(positionCoord: GLKVector3(v: (-0.5, 0.5, -0.5)), textureCoord: GLKVector2(v: (1, 0)))
        self.vertices[23] = CubeVertex(positionCoord: GLKVector3(v: (-0.5, -0.5, -0.5)), textureCoord: GLKVector2(v: (0, 0)))

        // right
        self.vertices[24] = CubeVertex(positionCoord: GLKVector3(v: (0.5, 0.5, 0.5)), textureCoord: GLKVector2(v: (1, 1)))
        self.vertices[25] = CubeVertex(positionCoord: GLKVector3(v: (0.5, -0.5, 0.5)), textureCoord: GLKVector2(v: (0, 1)))
        self.vertices[26] = CubeVertex(positionCoord: GLKVector3(v: (0.5, 0.5, -0.5)), textureCoord: GLKVector2(v: (1, 0)))

        self.vertices[27] = CubeVertex(positionCoord: GLKVector3(v: (0.5, -0.5, 0.5)), textureCoord: GLKVector2(v: (0, 1)))
        self.vertices[28] = CubeVertex(positionCoord: GLKVector3(v: (0.5, 0.5, -0.5)), textureCoord: GLKVector2(v: (1, 0)))
        self.vertices[29] = CubeVertex(positionCoord: GLKVector3(v: (0.5, -0.5, -0.5)), textureCoord: GLKVector2(v: (0, 0)))

        // back
        self.vertices[30] = CubeVertex(positionCoord: GLKVector3(v: (-0.5, 0.5, -0.5)), textureCoord: GLKVector2(v: (0, 1)))
        self.vertices[31] = CubeVertex(positionCoord: GLKVector3(v: (-0.5, -0.5, -0.5)), textureCoord: GLKVector2(v: (0, 0)))
        self.vertices[32] = CubeVertex(positionCoord: GLKVector3(v: (0.5, 0.5, -0.5)), textureCoord: GLKVector2(v: (1, 1)))

        self.vertices[33] = CubeVertex(positionCoord: GLKVector3(v: (-0.5, -0.5, -0.5)), textureCoord: GLKVector2(v: (0, 0)))
        self.vertices[34] = CubeVertex(positionCoord: GLKVector3(v: (0.5, 0.5, -0.5)), textureCoord: GLKVector2(v: (1, 1)))
        self.vertices[35] = CubeVertex(positionCoord: GLKVector3(v: (0.5, -0.5, -0.5)), textureCoord: GLKVector2(v: (1, 0)))


        glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer)
        glBindBuffer(GLenum(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER), vertexBuffer)
        let bufferSize = MemoryLayout<CubeVertex>.size * kCoordCount
        glBufferData(GLenum(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER), bufferSize, self.vertices, GLenum(GL_STATIC_DRAW))


        glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLuint(GLKVertexAttrib.position.rawValue))
        glVertexAttribPointer(GLuint(GLKVertexAttrib.position.rawValue), 3, GLenum(GL_FLOAT), GLboolean(GL_FALSE), GLsizei(MemoryLayout<CubeVertex>.size), BUFFER_OFFSET(0))


        glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLuint(GLKVertexAttrib.texCoord0.rawValue))
        glVertexAttribPointer(GLuint(GLKVertexAttrib.texCoord0.rawValue), 2, GLenum(GL_FLOAT), GLboolean(GL_FALSE), GLsizei(MemoryLayout<CubeVertex>.size), BUFFER_OFFSET(MemoryLayout<GLKVector3>.size))

    }

    private func BUFFER_OFFSET(_ i: Int) -> UnsafeRawPointer? {
        return UnsafeRawPointer(bitPattern: i)
    }

    private func addDisplayLink() {
        displayLink.add(to: RunLoop.main, forMode: .common)
    }

    @objc private   func glkViewDisplay() {
        angle = (angle + 3) % 360
        let radians = GLKMathDegreesToRadians(Float(angle))
        baseEffect.transform.modelviewMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeRotation(radians, 0.5, 0.3, 0.4)
        glkView.display()
    }
}

extension ViewController: GLKViewDelegate {
    func glkView(_ view: GLKView, drawIn rect: CGRect) {
        glEnable(GLenum(GL_DEPTH_TEST))
        glClear(GLbitfield(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT))
        baseEffect.prepareToDraw()
        glDrawArrays(GLenum(GL_TRIANGLES), 0, GLsizei(kCoordCount))
    }
}
```

The problem may appear in the code below:

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLuint(GLKVertexAttrib.texCoord0.rawValue))
glVertexAttribPointer(GLuint(GLKVertexAttrib.texCoord0.rawValue), 2, GLenum(GL_FLOAT), GLboolean(GL_FALSE), GLsizei(MemoryLayout<CubeVertex>.size), BUFFER_OFFSET(MemoryLayout<GLKVector3>.size))
```

But i don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the way to solve this problem. But the reason also confused me. Use the below code:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(GLuint(GLKVertexAttrib.texCoord0.rawValue), 2, GLenum(GL_FLOAT), GLboolean(GL_FALSE), GLsizei(MemoryLayout<CubeVertex>.size), BUFFER_OFFSET(MemoryLayout<GLKVector3>.size + 4))
```

replace the code:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(GLuint(GLKVertexAttrib.texCoord0.rawValue), 2, GLenum(GL_FLOAT), GLboolean(GL_FALSE), GLsizei(MemoryLayout<CubeVertex>.size), BUFFER_OFFSET(MemoryLayout<GLKVector3>.size))
```

It can solve the problem. that means the offset is `16` rather than `12`. It also have two question confused me:

1. The `CubeVertex` size is `24` not `20`.
2. The offset is `16` not `12`

Comment: The compiler is adding padding for the GLKit vector types. Note that the padding is inconsistent across implentations - macOS and iOS will generally return different values for the type sizes.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15906996/sizeof-returns-wrong-size-for-struct-which-contains-glkvector3-glkvector4-var