# Strange behaviour of openmp collapse directive

Tags: c++, clang, openmp

I have the following problem:

In the code below I wait the same amount of iterations, but this is not true. Often I have 45 iterations(expected amount), some times I have 67, some times 23 iterations. How does `#pragma omp parallel for collapse(2)` works, or maybe I wrongly used `#pragma omp critical`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec(45);
    int k = 0;
    #pragma omp parallel for collapse(2)
     for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < 10; ++j) {
            auto tmp = big_calc();
            #pragma omp critical
                vec[k++] = tmp;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think it is because of j initial value

Comment: added crutch - in nested for j now starts from 0 and added: ```if (i  >= j) continue;```

Comment: What about [reading the documentation](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu41.html#x64-1290002.9.2)? Moreover, the `#pragma omp critical` prevent any possible parallel speed-up and the sequential version should be actually much faster. You need to **redesign your algorithm** so it could *really run in parallel*.

Comment: in this part of code - ```auto tmp = j * (i + 1);``` in original code i do some big calculation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is **not compliant to the OpenMP standard**.
Indeed, the initializer `int j = i + 1` of the inner loop [shall not be dependent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47758947/c-openmp-nested-loops-where-the-inner-iterator-depends-on-the-outer-one) of the iterator value of the outer loop. You should **collapse the loop yourself** (or you can use OpenMP tasks which have a higher overhead).

PS: `#pragma omp critical` is not needed anymore if you collapse the loop yourself (resulting in a better scalability).