# Segfault when fusing double for-loop

Tags: c, for-loop, pointers, parallel-processing, openmp

I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24013832/fusing-a-triangle-loop-for-parallelization-calculating-sub-indices) on how to fuse a loop. The goal is to fuse my double `for` loop in order to parallelize it with OpenMP. The reason why I don't use `collapse(2)` is because the inner loop has dependencies on the outer one. I have also read this relevant [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28482833/understanding-the-collapse-clause-in-openmp?noredirect=1&lq=1).

My problem though, is that when I fuse my loop I get a `Segmentation Fault` error and that sounds pretty fuzzy. I am pretty sure I am making the right conversion. Unfortunately there is no way I can provide a reproducible - minimal example as my program has a ton of functions where they call one another. Here is my initial loop though:

```
for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
{  
    int counter = 0;
    for(int j=0; j<size; j++)
    {
        if (i==j)
            continue;
        if(arr[size * i + j])
        {
          
            graph->nodes[i]->degree++;
            graph->nodes[i]->neighbours[counter] = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
            graph->nodes[i]->neighbours[counter] = graph->nodes[j];
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

where `graph` is a `pointer` to `Struct` and `graph->nodes` is an array of pointers to the graph's nodes. Same goes for `graph->nodes[i]->neighbours`. An array of pointers (pointed to by a pointer pointed to by another pointer - sorry).

As you can see the fact that I am using the `counter` variable
that restricts me from using `#pragma omp parallel for collapse(2)`. Below you can see my converted loop:

```
for(int n=0; n<size*size; n++)
{  
    int i = n / size;
    int j = n % size;
    int counter = 0;
    for(int j=0; j<size; j++)
    {
        if (i==j)
            continue;
        if(arr[size * i + j])
        {
          
            graph->nodes[i]->degree++;
            graph->nodes[i]->neighbours[counter] = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
            graph->nodes[i]->neighbours[counter] = graph->nodes[j];
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried debugging with `valgrind` and what's ultra weird is that the `Segmentation Fault` **does not appear to be on these specific lines**, **although it happens only when I make the loop conversion**.

*Mini disclaimer*: As you may guess, because of these pointer to pointer to pointer variables I use lots of `malloc`s.

I don't expect you to get the same error with the code that I have posted that is why my question is more of a general one: How could theoretically a loop fusion cause a segfault error?

Comment: You're allocating memory for a node with `graph->nodes[i]->neighbours[counter] = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));`, but the next line throws that memory away.

Comment: @SteveFriedl That's a catch. Thanks! I wasn't sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your *converted* loop you got `i` and `j` mixed up.

It should be `int i = n % size;`, not `j`.

`n / size` always equals 0.

Comment: Sorry that's not the case. It was just a typo. I fixed it. It's `size*size` so `n/size` doesn't always give `0`.Although thanks for noticing.