# No Memory Alignment with GCC

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction, compiler-optimization, memory-alignment

I am working with some packet data. I have created structs to hold the packet data. These structs have been generated by python for a specific networking protocol.

The issue is that due to the fact that the compiler aligns the structures, when I send the data via the networking protocol, the message ends up being longer than I would like. This causes the other device to not recognize the command.

Does anyone know possible a work around this so that my packers are exactly the size the struct should be or is there a way I can turn off memory alignment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In GCC, you can use `__attribute__((packed))`.  These days GCC supports `#pragma pack`, too.

1. [`attribute` documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Type-Attributes.html)
2. [`#pragma pack` documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structure_002dPacking-Pragmas.html)

Examples:

1. `attribute` method:

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>

   struct packed
   {
       char a;
       int b;
   } __attribute__((packed));

   struct not_packed
   {
       char a;
       int b;
   };

   int main(void)
   {
       printf("Packed:     %zu\n", sizeof(struct packed));
       printf("Not Packed: %zu\n", sizeof(struct not_packed));
       return 0;
   }
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   $ make example && ./example
   cc     example.c   -o example
   Packed:     5
   Not Packed: 8
   ```
2. `pragma pack` method:

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>

   #pragma pack(1)
   struct packed
   {
       char a;
       int b;
   };
   #pragma pack()

   struct not_packed
   {
       char a;
       int b;
   };

   int main(void)
   {
       printf("Packed:     %zu\n", sizeof(struct packed));
       printf("Not Packed: %zu\n", sizeof(struct not_packed));
       return 0;
   }
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   $ make example && ./example
   cc     example.c   -o example
   Packed:     5
   Not Packed: 8
   ```

Comment: IIRC, the `#pragma pack` is a hack for compatibility with MS compilers, and thus only avaliable for x86 targets. If you want to be portable to other targets (but not VC++) you should use the former. If you want both, you'll have to use `#ifdef`s.

Comment: I think it works for other targets too, but I'd have to check.

Comment: @roderigo #pragma pack is for all architectures in gcc. There's a #pragma ms_struct on on some architectures that's for microsoft compatibility

Comment: But see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8568432/827263); if you're not careful, `#pragma pack` can lead to unsafe code.

Comment: @KeithThompson, well as soon as you talk abut messing with the compiler options, you are talking about getting unsafe code. You just have to be really careful in either case.

Comment: @Edwin: Not necessarily. For example, if `-O3` causes unsafe code, it's a bug (either in the compiler or in the code that it's compiling).