# Compile without memory alignment in GCC

Tags: c, gcc

I'm testing a buffer overflow exploitation but when I compile my code, gcc uses memory alignment and the extra bytes added by the compiler force me to deal with this padding.

Is there a way to compile the code with gcc without padding?

This is the overflow achieved with padding but I want a clear view of it without compiler garbage:

```
(gdb) x/60x 0xbffff450
0xbffff450: 0xbffff460  0x00000001  0x00000000  0x00000001
0xbffff460: *0x41414141 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141[buffer begins]
0xbffff470: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0xbffff480: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0xbffff490: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141*[buffer ends]
0xbffff4a0: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141 [0x0804851c][Return Address]
```

Regards

Edit:

This is the code I'm compiling:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *secret = "pepito";

void go_shell(){
    char *shell = "/bin/sh";
    char *cmd[] = { "/bin/sh", 0 };
    printf("¿Quieres jugar a un juego?...\n");
    setreuid(0);
    execve(shell,cmd,0);
}

int authorize(){
    char password[64];
    printf("Escriba la contraseña: ");
    gets(password);
    if (!strcmp(password,secret))
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

int main(){
    if (authorize()){
        printf("Acceso permitido\n");
        go_shell();
    } else{
        printf("Acceso denegado\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possibly related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18341540/no-memory-alignment-with-gcc .

Comment: You can use `#define packed_data __attribute__((__packed__))` and prefix your structs with it

Comment: @janisz In my code I don't use data structs, the padding is applied to the var password 64 bytes long.

Comment: Oh, I see. I can't check it right now but have you tried [-fno-align-commons](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Code-Gen-Options.html)

Comment: @janisz This is the output of GCC: cc1: warning: command line option ‘-fno-align-commons’ is valid for Fortran but not for C [enabled by default]

Comment: @janisz Also this is the memory with the buffer filled with 64 A http://pastebin.com/qnMf29PQ . Notice that after the buffer, there are 8Bytes of junk plus EBP and finally the return address.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you need to adjust how gcc allocates stack space. By default, it attempts to keep the stack aligned on 16-byte boundaries since certain instructions (SSE*) require it. If you specify `-mpreferred-stack-boundary=2` on the command line when you compile, gcc will keep the stack aligned to 2^2=4, which what you were expecting since you are using a 32-bit environment.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, now the structure is Buffer+EBP+RA Thank you very much

Comment: `gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4` throws: `error: -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2 is not between 4 and 12`

Comment: @ΑναστάσηςΑνδρονίδης, sounds like have a 64-bit system, not a 32-bit system.

Comment: @AnastasiosAndronidis add an `-m32` to compile a 32bit ELF.