# __packed qualifier ignored

Tags: gcc, android-ndk, arm, alignment, gcc-warning

Why I get a `'__packed__' attribute ignored [-Wattributes]` warning in an android NDK Project?

Here is the code

```
    mem_ = malloc(size_);

    uint8_t* ui8_ptr = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(mem_);
    *ui8_ptr++ = packet_version;

    //uint32_t* ui32_ptr = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(ui8_ptr);
    __packed uint32_t* ui32_ptr = (__packed uint32_t*)(ui8_ptr);
    *ui32_ptr++ = size_;
    *ui32_ptr++ = flags;
```

I am using the packed attribute because I think I have alignment problem when casting from uint8_t to uint32_t (See [1]).

[1] http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka15414.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCC doesn't seem to support the packed attribute for all variables. It is only supported for `struct`, `union`, and `enum` types. So you could try something like this instead:

```
mem_ = malloc(size_);

uint8_t* ui8_ptr = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(mem_);
*ui8_ptr++ = packet_version;

struct unaligned32_t
{
    uint32_t data __attribute__((packed, aligned(1)));
};
//unaligned32_t* ui32_ptr = reinterpret_cast<unaligned32_t*>(ui8_ptr);
unaligned32_t* ui32_ptr = (unaligned32_t*)(ui8_ptr);
(ui32_ptr++)->data = size_;
(ui32_ptr++)->data = flags;
```

This won't produce the warning unless you use it on a `char` type, which is already byte aligned anyway.

I'm still investigating if this produces the code I'm aiming for on my ARM micro-controller but it is the only legal way I can think of using the *packed* attribute.

**Here be dragons!** Don't take the address of `unaligned32_t.data`. You should only access the `data` member of the struct using the `.` or `->` directly, and not via a pointer. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8568441/1667513) for why.

Answer (score 0):

Link you referenced is for RVDS compiler (probably armcc) and GCC doesn't support [`packed`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Type-Attributes.html) attribute on pointers for such usage.