# C struct elements alignment (ansi)

Tags: c++, c, standards, memory-alignment, ansi-c

just a simple question... what the standard says about the structure members alignment?
for example with this one:

```
struct
{
    uint8_t a;
    uint8_t b;
    /* other members */
} test;
```

It is guarateed that b is at offset 1 from the struct start?
Thanks

Comment: I added this to my answer late, not sure how I forgot about it but [offsetof](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof) may be helpful.

Answer (score 7):

The standard (as of C99) doesn't really say anything.

The only real guarantees are that `(void *)&test == (void *)&a`, and that `a` is at a lower address than `b`.  Everything else is up to the implementation.

Comment: A lot of compilers have the rather handy library macro [offsetof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offsetof) though.

Comment: C11 has _Alignof, ANSI C doesn't.

Comment: The first guarantee unobsfucated: `a` is at offset `0`.

Answer (score 1):

*C11 6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers* p14 says

> Each non-bit-field member of a structure or union object is aligned in
>   an implementation- defined manner appropriate to its type.

meaning that you can't make any portable assumptions about the difference between the addresses of `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to use [offsetof](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof) to determine the offset of members.

For C the alignment is implementation defined, we can see that in the draft C99 standard section `6.7.2.1` *Structure and union specifiers* paragraph *12*(In C11 it would be paragraph 14) which says:

> Each non-bit-field member of a structure or union object is aligned in an implementation defined manner appropriate to its type.

and paragraph *13* says:

> Within a structure object, the non-bit-field members and the units in which bit-fields
>   reside have addresses that increase in the order in which they are declared. A pointer to a
>   structure object, suitably converted, points to its initial member (or if that member is a
>   bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa. There may be unnamed
>   padding within a structure object, but not at its beginning.

and for *C++* we have the following similar quotes from the draft standard section  `9.2` *Class members* paragraph *13* says:

> Nonstatic data members of a (non-union) class with the same access control (Clause 11) are allocated so that later members have higher addresses within a class object. The order of allocation of non-static data members with different access control is unspecified (Clause 11). Implementation alignment requirements might cause two adjacent members not to be allocated immediately after each other;

and paragraph *19* says:

> A pointer to a standard-layout struct object, suitably converted using a reinterpret_cast, points to its
>   initial member (or if that member is a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides) and vice versa. [ Note:
>   There might therefore be unnamed padding within a standard-layout struct object, but not at its beginning,
>   as necessary to achieve appropriate alignment. —end note ]

Answer (score 0):

the case you're using is not really an edge case, both uint_8 are small enough to fit in the same word in memory and it would be no use to put each uint_8 in a uint_16.

A more critical case would be something like :

```
{
    uint8_t a;
    uint8_t b;

    uint_32 c; // where is C, at &a+2 or &a+4 ?
    /* other members */
} test;
```

and anyway this will always depend on the target architecture and your compiler...

Answer (score 0):

K&R second edition (ANSI C) in chapter 6.4 (page 138) says:

> Don't assume, however, that the size of a structure is the sum of the sizes of its memebers. Because of alignment requirements for different objects, there may be unnamed "holes" in a structure.

So no, ANSI C does not guarantee that `b` is at offset 1.

It is even likely that the compiler puts `b` at offset `sizeof(int)` so that it's aligned on the size of a machine word, which is easier to deal with.

Some compilers support [pack-pragmas](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structure-Packing-Pragmas.html) so that you can force that there are no such "holes" in the `struct`, but that is not portable.

Answer (score 0):

What is guaranteed by the C-Standard already had been mentioned by other answers.

However, to make sure `b` **is** at offset `1` your compiler might offer options to "pack" the structure, will say to explicitly add **no** padding.

For gcc this can be achieved by the [`#pragma` `pack()`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structure-Packing-Pragmas.html#Structure-Packing-Pragmas).

```
#pragma pack(1)
struct
{
  uint8_t a; /* Guaranteed to be at offset 0. */
  uint8_t b; /* Guaranteed to be at offset 1. */
  /* other members are guaranteed to start at offset 2. */
} test_packed;
#pragma pack()

struct
{
  uint8_t a; /* Guaranteed to by at offset 0. */
  uint8_t b; /* NOT guaranteed to be at offset 1. */
  /* other members are NOT guaranteed to start at offset 2. */
} test_unpacked;
```

---

A portable (and save) solution would be to simply use an array:

```
struct
{
  uint8_t ab[2]; /* ab[0] is guaranteed to be at offset 0. */
                 /* ab[1] is guaranteed to be at offset 1. */
  /* other members are NOT guaranteed to start at offset 2. */
} test_packed;
```

Comment: Yes, but `#pragma pack` isn't necessarily safe; see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8568432/827263)

Comment: @KeithThompson: This is correct. So I'd propose to go for the array-based solution.