# Is assignment to a std::vector element thread-safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, threadpool, stdvector

I have made a thread pool which writes to the same vector at the same time.

Is this implementation thread safe?

If it is not, how should I fix it?

```
std::vector<double> global_var;

void func1(int i)
{
    global_var[i]=some_computation(i /* only depends on i */);
}

void load_distribution()
{
    const int N_max=100;
    global_var.assign(N_max,0.0);
    std::vector<std::thread> th_pool;
    for(long i=0;i<N_max;i++)
        th_pool.push_back(std::thread(func1,i));

    for(std::thread& tp : th_pool)
        tp.join();
}
```

---

**Update**

`global_var` will not be touched by any other part of the program before all threads terminated.

Comment: While I hate to admit, the current snippet is actually thread safe. ...Still, your design is really fragile. There may be another portion of your code that may modify `global_var` which will introduce Undefined Behavior

Comment: @WhiZTiM I guarantee, `global_var` will not be changed by any other part of the program before all threads terminate.

Comment: the complete code [here](http://pastebin.com/S3GYTYBf) for just in case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your *global* vector is not modified by any other part of code, then your code is thread safe.

Each thread is going to write (access) into a different cell of the vector, so there is no *"dirty update"* problem.

Moreover the vector's type is a double, in a modern architecture is bigger than a WORD-size. So each array cell is not overlapped among others.

Comment: Thank you very much. What if I use a `vector<complicatedObj>`. Can it make any problem?

Comment: @ar2015 Not if there memory is allocated in an aligned way

Comment: what is aligned way of memory allocation or what is an example of non-aligned way?

Comment: @ar2015 I've answer that question some months ago. If you want see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38875369/what-is-data-alignment-why-and-when-should-i-be-worried-when-typecasting-pointe/38875855#38875855)

Comment: As you are talking, if I use `vector<complicatedObj>` where `complicatedObj` contains several `vector`s itself, the code may fail. I am correct?

Comment: @ar2015 If each thread will access a different index, without any data-race and the memory is aligned, then there are no reasons the code should fail. Even with very complicated object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131872/discussion-between-biagio-festa-and-ar2015).

Answer (score 4):

[[container.requirements.dataraces]/1-2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/container.requirements.dataraces):

> 1 For purposes of avoiding data races ([res.on.data.races]),
>   implementations shall consider the following functions to be `const`:
>   `begin`, `end`, `rbegin`, `rend`, `front`, `back`, `data`, [...], `at` and, except in associative or unordered
>   associative containers, `operator[]`.
>
> 2 Notwithstanding ([res.on.data.races]), implementations are required
>   to avoid data races when the contents of the contained object in
>   different elements in the same container, excepting `vector<bool>`, are
>   modified concurrently.

Answer (score -1):

Generally, `std::vector` is not thread safe, but the above code will work because the backing array is preallocated with `assign()` method.

As long as the writers don't cause reallocating the backing array, the code will work. The `assign()` method will preallocate enough space so it will not happen when the thread write to it.

Comment: actually, an assignment has already been used `global_var.assign(N_max,0.0);`

Comment: What if instead of `vector<double>`, I use `vector<object>` which will contain other vectors inside themselves. In this case, does assignment invalidate the vector?

Comment: @ar2015 : No, it wouldn't modify the outside vector, it would touch only the content of each element. And as the outside backing array wouldn't be modified, the modification of the particular elements would be thread safe. Of course, as long as there would be just single thread touching each of them.