# Yet another confusion about data alignment and padding

Tags: c++, c, memory

I've been reading about data alignment and structure padding.I've started from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) and just to express my understanding, I can say an element or a data `e` of type `T` is naturally aligned if its address `a`is a multiple of its data size[`sizeof T`],

let's consider

```
struct test{
 short a;
 char b;
};
```

`constexpr auto size = sizeof test` is 4 due to `struct test`'s max alignment(`short`)

and then I went [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38875369/what-is-data-alignment-why-and-when-should-i-be-worried-when-typecasting-pointe), the very first answer did a good explanation about data alignment, the author used this example

```
data1: "ab"
data2: "cdef"

|a b c d|     |e f 0 0|
```

Given the memory access granularity is 4 byte, I am going to make an assumption here like `data1` is of `2` byte and `data2` is of `4 byte`, since the `data2` begins at an odd address or its address isn't the multiple of `4 byte` which is considered as a  misaligned data, so accessing `data2` will have a different effect based on the architecture.

here comes the padding to make `data2` to be naturally aligned by adding junkies(or pure 0s), at the end we have

`|a b 0 0|     |c d e f|`

So far fine, now let's wrap the two data' into a struct

```
struct wrap{
    data1: "ab"
    data2: "cdef"
};
```

Now by considering the max alignment, the `wrap` size would become `8` with two-byte padding.

here I am, in the case of `struct wrap` whether it is with padding or without padding the processor actually needs two cycles(given a WORD size is 4 byte) to fetch the `wrap` object right?
so why do we need padding?

without padding:

`|a b c d|     |e f 0 0|`

assume the processor fetched the 8 byte `wrap object`, `data1` is of two bytes so it can hold "ab" remaining will be truncated (just as how padded bits would be truncated)
and `data2` can read consecutive 4 bytes from its address (which reads "cdef") rest were truncated, So why do we need padding here or I just got it wrong?

the second question which more or less similar to above

```
struct test2{
    short a; //2 byte
    char _3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11 ;
};
```

and the `sizeof test2` will give 12, given now the memory access granularity(changing WORD = 8) is 8-byte then the  `test2`'s object gonna occupy two WORD, again with or without padding it is going to occupy two WORD, so two cycles needed regardless of `test2`'s alignment to fetch its object, if this is the case why does padding matter here? why 12, not 11 though both needs two cycles in an 8-byte boundary?

final question,

```
struct final{
  char a;
  int b;
};
```

let's say the `struct final` is packed(no alignment) and the var `test::b` going to be placed at the odd address

memory ( just a theoretical representation)

```
0          1          2          3          4          5          6         7
tets::a:1  test::b:1  test::b:2  test::b:3  test::b:4
```

`test::b:x` am not meaning bit fields here

I've learned that as long I access test::b using object via `. or ->' it will be fine but when I take the address of it

`int * p = &(test::b) ; (void)*p;` this statements will either take a performance hit or crash.

Again if the WORD = 8 bytes then the `struct final`'s object  will get into memory in one cycle and let's say the pointer `p` holds the address `1` which is odd, but can't just the deference of `*p` copy the bits starting from address `1` up to its pointing to element type( 4-byte )into memory? why there is a problem here? what I've been missing to account for?

Answer (score 3):

The problem with data misalignment is not related to load/store of whole structs. It appears with access to individual fields.

When a field is misaligned, it takes two read/writes plus byte rearrangement, instead of one. The padded struct is larger, and we don't mind.

Comment: In one of the instances I showed above `struct final`  can fit into a WORD boundary(given WORD=8) , and assume I access its individual element  `int b` with pointer `p` that  holds its address `1`, so  here, what is the problem of just reading 4-byte off from the given address? why there would be a hit/crash?

Comment: @Explorer_N: if the machine performs fetches of 8 bytes even for a misaligned int, it will need to realign the field internally anyway. If it uses 4 byte aligned fetches, two of them will be required.

Comment: sorry, when I `@ ` mention the name is not appearing.

"to realign the field internally " I am kinda stuck here, we've fetched 8-byte and the pointer `p`  knows where to start reading within the 8-byte boundary, it also knows how many bytes it can read, so when we say `temp=*p` why can't it do a bitwise copy like(example) `memcpy(&tmp,p,sizeof(int))` why there is a need for a realignment? or it is simply a rule that an address of an `int` element should be a multiple of 4?

Comment: @Explorer_N: the memory bus may be designed in such a way that it is unable to perform misaligned reads.