# How endianness swaps the order of elements, when converting two elements of uint32_t array to a single uint64_t?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, memory, endianness

I am confused as to how, endianness swaps the ordering of elements of a `uint32_t` array when converted to a `uint64_t` and vice-versa.

If I'm dealing with bytes stored in a uint8_t array of 8 elements, if I directly convert it to a `uint64_t` using pointer casting and dereference like this:

```
uint8_t array[8] = {0xaa, 0xbb, 0xcc, 0xdd, 0xee, 0xff, 0xb0, 0xa0};
uint64_t u = *(uint64_t *)array;
```

On a little endian system, `u` would be equal to `0xa0b0ffeeddccbbaa`

But, if I have a `uint32_t` array like this:

```
uint32_t arr[2] = {0xaabbccdd, 0xeeffb0a0} ;
uint64_t U = *(uint64_t *)arr;
```

On a little endian system, `U` becomes `0xeeffb0a0aabbccdd`

I intuitively understand the former case, but the latter, with the `uint32_t` is confusing!
I have trouble visualizing the memory layout, during conversion, in the latter case...
Every help, will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Endianess takes hold from inception on the `uint32_t arr[2]`. Both of those `uint32_t` values are stored in platform-specific endian representation. That is not the case for the first sample and a `uint8_t` base array. Consider that.

Comment: Aside, "On a little endian system, u would be equal to 0xa0b0ffeeddccbbaa" -> code `*(uint64_t *)array` risks alignment issues.

Comment: @WhozCraig Can you please clarify more ? :)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Can you elaborate more on alignment issues ?

Comment: See [What is data alignment? Why and when should I be worried when typecasting pointers in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38875369/what-is-data-alignment-why-and-when-should-i-be-worried-when-typecasting-pointe)

Comment: Example would speak louder than anything else.  Think of what you're doing, but backward. [Look at this](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/17ebf380b7e91a7c). Consider what endian representation is doing with each of those `uint32_t` values in that array of two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Endianess applies *individually* on every integer of 16 bits or larger. That is, on a little endian machine, a 32 bit integer `0xaabbccdd` is stored as `dd cc bb aa`.

So an array of two 32 integers `uint32_t [2]` with the values `0x11223344` and `0x55667788` are stored as
`44 33 22 11` and `88 77 66 55` respectively. In an array, items are guaranteed to get stored contiguously, so in this case the memory will look like `44 33 22 11 88 77 66 55`.

A 64 bit integer `0x1122334455667788` is however stored as `88 77 66 55 44 33 22 11`, because again, endianess applies individually to each integer. This is why you can't re-interpret the memory layout of two 32 bit integers as a 64 bit integer on little endian machines.

If the CPU had been big endian however, the `uint32_t [2]` would have been stored as:
`11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88` and then it happens to get the same representation as a `uint64_t` with the value `0x1122334455667788`.

---

As a sidenote, the `*(uint64_t *)array` conversions in your code are undefined behavior because they violate strict pointer aliasing and could possibly also give misalignment. To convert between different memory types safely, you need to use bit shifts, `memcpy` or `union`.

Comment: Thankyou, very much for your answer! Because of your answer, I got the concept very clearly ! :) But, I've been using this technique conversion, for efficiency reasons. But, as per your advice I'm **going** to use ```memcpy``` / ```union``` ! :)