# Loading a file into a structure

Tags: c++, gcc

I have this as my basic code.

```
struct TABLE
{
    unsigned char a[2];
    unsigned char b[8];
    unsigned short c;
};
```

The best way I have of describing this is, I can successfully read from a file and place the data into &TABLE. I have read the data here and it is all good.

However,

```
&TABLE.a = 0x0000FF00
&TABLE.b = 0x0000FF03
&TABLE.c = 0x0000FF0C
```

&TABLE.c should be 0x0000FF0B.

What gets really interesting is if I change, b to [7] from [8]. &Table.c then returns 0x0000FF0A

What is the logic here?

Comment: Provide some [mre] in your question. Compile your C++ code with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`. Use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger to understand the behavior of your program. Perhaps use the [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/). Consider using [sqlite](https://sqlite.org/)

Comment: `&TABLE.b = 0x0000FF03`, are you sure? That doesn't make sense to me. I expect it to be `0x0000FF02`. I don't understand why there's a byte of padding between `a` and `b`. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Yes, I double checked.

Comment: you could try explicitely set alignment of those chars, as for ex. `unsigned char alignas(2) a[2];` and `unsigned char alignas(2) b[8];`

Comment: The strange behavior with `[7]` is explained by [alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38875369/what-is-data-alignment-why-and-when-should-i-be-worried-when-typecasting-pointe). See the link for a detailed explanation.

Comment: I can't provide a sample because it's being done on another computer and my net access is just a mobile phone.

Comment: A minimal example would just be a struct and a `main` that prints the addresses of its members. That can be entered on a phone without much trouble (after you have verified its misbehaviour on the actual computer, of course).

Comment: You could prepare an MCVE in an online compiler like e.g. [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/).

Comment: To solve alignment issues as well as big/little endianess one may resort to boost's serialization. https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html

Answer (score 0):

What was needed was

```
__attributes__ ((packed))
```

Thankyou to everyone and the person who mentioned alignments so I could go off and read into that. :)

Comment: Perhaps not. Since using that will slow down your code significantly (on x86-64 and perhaps even on x86 32 bits or ARM)