# Is there equivalent functionality to C# Structs/StructLayout with field offsets in C++?

Tags: c#, c++

Take this example of a C# struct:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    public struct Example
    {
        [FieldOffset(0x10)]
        public IntPtr examplePtr;

        [FieldOffset(0x18)]
        public IntPtr examplePtr2;

        [FieldOffset(0x54)]
        public int exampleInt;
    }
```

I can take an array of bytes, and transform it to this struct like so:

```
    public static T GetStructure<T>(byte[] bytes)
    {
        var handle = GCHandle.Alloc(bytes, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        var structure = (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(T));
        handle.Free();
        return structure;
    }

    public static T GetStructure<T>(byte[] bytes, int index)
    {
        var size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));
        var tmp = new byte[size];
        Array.Copy(bytes, index, tmp, 0, size);
        return GetStructure<T>(tmp);
    }

    GetStructure<Example>(arrayOfBytes);
```

Is there equivalent functionality in C++ to take an array of bytes and transform it to a struct, where not all bytes are used in the transformation (C# structlayout.explicit w/ field offsets)?

I **don't** want to do something like the following:

```
struct {
  pad_bytes[0x10];
  DWORD64 = examplePtr;
  DWORD64 = examplePtr2;
  pad_bytes2[0x44];
  int exampleInt;
}
```

Comment: The last snippet exposes the way it might work or it might not. The compiler might adjust the alignment of members to its own preferences. If you want a reliable way, you may use an array of `char` (or `unsigned char`) and `memcpy()` the values at the appropriate offsets. Thereby, endianess might be another issue to care about. Beside of endianess, this will, of course, work for primitive types only. Maybe, provide a bit more context to prevent talking about an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: Is there a particular reason adding padding members won't work for you, or is it just the ugliness it creates? Keep in mind that the padding solution should have the equivalent of `[[gnu::packed]]`.

Comment: FYI: [My attempt to write an MS Bitmap in a portable way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56054487/7478597) puzzling it byte for byte together according to the found spec. It's done in C but it wouldn't look much different in C++ (except that I would prefer `fstream` instead of Cs `FILE` API).

Comment: @Scheff I'm aware of how it likely works internally, but to explain and also answer chris, it's the general ugliness of having to put pads within each struct.

Comment: It's the clean way to do it though, if you want to stick go the typed approach. Otherwise you may just write simple marshalling code for packing/unpacking bin-data into a struct of unspecified data layout.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38942125/how-to-set-structure-element-at-desired-offset

Comment: what about `#define FIELD_OFFSET(X) char _offset_padding_##__COUNTER__ [X]` ?

Comment: bitfields, POD & alignas?

Answer (score 0):

No, I am not aware of a way to specify the byte offset of some struct member - there is definitely nothing in the standard, and I don't know of any compiler specific extension.

In addition to padding members (as you already mentioned), you can also use [`alignas`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas), [`#pragma pack`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/pack?view=vs-2019), and [`__declspec(align(#))`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/align-cpp?view=vs-2019) (on MSVC), and [`__attribute__ ((packed))`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3/gcc/Type-Attributes.html) and [`__attribute__ ((aligned(#)))`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html) (on GCC). Of course these don't let you specify the offset, but they can help control the layout of your struct.

The best I can think of to ensure that your layout matches your expectations is using `static_assert` with [`offsetof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof):

```
struct Example{
  char pad_bytes[0x10];
  DWORD64 examplePtr;
  DWORD64 examplePtr2;
  char pad_bytes2[0x44];
  int exampleInt;
};
static_assert(offsetof(Example, examplePtr) == 0x10);
static_assert(offsetof(Example, examplePtr2) == 0x18);
static_assert(offsetof(Example, exampleInt) == 0x54);
```