# Bitfield and Union - unexpected result in C

Tags: c, unions, bit-fields

I've been given the following assignment in a C-course:

[image]

I've implemented the assignment to decode the *8 byte long long int 131809282883593* as follows:

```
    #include  <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>

    struct Message {
         unsigned int hour : 5;
         unsigned int minutes : 6;
         unsigned int seconds : 6;
         unsigned int day : 5;
         unsigned int month : 4;
         unsigned int year : 12;
         unsigned long long int code : 26;
    };  // 64 bit in total

    union Msgdecode {
        long long  int datablob;
        struct Message elems;
    };

    int main(void) {

        long long int datablob = 131809282883593;
        union Msgdecode m;

        m.datablob = datablob;

        printf("%d:%d:%d %d.%d.%d code:%lu\n", m.elems.hour, m.elems.minutes,
        m.elems.seconds, m.elems.day, m.elems.month, m.elems.year,(long unsigned int) m.elems.code); 

        union Msgdecode m2;
        m2.elems.hour = 9;
        m2.elems.minutes = 0;
        m2.elems.seconds = 0;
        m2.elems.day = 30;
        m2.elems.month = 5;
        m2.elems.year = 2017;
        m2.elems.code = 4195376;

        printf("m2.datablob: should: 131809282883593 is: %lld\n", m2.datablob); //WHY does m2.datablob != m.datablob?! 
        printf("m.datablob:  should: 131809282883593 is: %lld\n", m.datablob);

        printf("%d:%d:%d %d.%d.%d code:%lu\n", m2.elems.hour, m2.elems.minutes,
          m2.elems.seconds, m2.elems.day, m2.elems.month, m2.elems.year, (long unsigned int) m2.elems.code);

    }
```

[TRY IT ONLINE.](http://rextester.com/TDOM63724)

..what gives me a hard time is the output. The decoding/encoding works nicely so far. *9:0:0 30.5.2017 and code 4195376 is expected*, but the difference in the 'datablob' really isn't - and i can't figure out why/where it stems from:

```
9:0:0 30.5.2017 code:4195376
m2.datablob: should: 131809282883593 is: 131810088189961
m.datablob:  should: 131809282883593 is: 131809282883593
9:0:0 30.5.2017 code:4195376
```

As you can see the datablob is *close* to the original - but not the original. I've consulted a coworker whos fluent in C about this - but we couldn't figure out the reason for this behaviour.

**Q: Why do the blobs differ from each other?**

Bonus-Q: When manipulating the union `Msgdecode` to include another field, a strange thing happens:

```
union Msgdecode {
    long long  int datablob;
    struct Message elems;
    char bytes[8];  // added this
};
```

Outcome:

```
9:0:0 30.5.2017 code:0
m2.datablob: should: 131809282883593 is: 8662973939721
m.datablob:  should: 131809282883593 is: 131809282883593
9:0:0 30.5.2017 code:4195376
```

PS: reading on SO about bitfields+union questions gave me the impression that they are rather unreliable. Can this be generally said?

Comment: If that's your assignment, it is an awful one. Bit-field structures have hardly any guarantees about their layout. Use shifts and masking! And there is no guarantee you can use otherr than `int`, `unsigned int` and `_Bool` bitfleids. As a sidenote: none of the types you use guarantees a spicif representation or width! If you need fixed widths, use fixed width types!

Comment: @Olaf it is my assignment. So my PS-Question at the end can be answered with 'Yes'? :)

Comment: Yes, but we are not a tutoring service. With that tutor get a good C book and filter the course material with the book's information. As a sidenote: Letting apart I never gave my students such an assignment: with the code: you would fail in my course. Some reasons: see above.

Comment: btw: thanks for the downvote, not.

Could the one who doesn't think i put enough effort into this (i think i realy have) please at least argue why he/she thinks this is a bad question? ..or how i could improve it?

Comment: I think this is a good, clearly asked question and it doesn't matter if it is a student assignment or not.

Comment: Olaf is correct in saying that bit-field structures have very little in the way of guarantees, their layout may vary from compiler to compiler and from architecture to architecture and even depending where in memory the structure is located WRT boundaries etc.

Comment: Are you sure that "9:0:0 30.5.2017 code:4195376" is the correct decoded value?

Comment: @dbush for the first part (the date)  i am very sure, because that's the exact date of the next session. Elems.code 4195376 ... Im not sure/don't know if it's correct.

Comment: @Gewure Taking the groups of bits from right to left, I'm getting "9:0:0 30.5.2127 code:479".  In particular, the 12 bits in the middle (26 before and 26 = 4 + 5 + 6 + 6 + 5 after) are 1000 0100 1111 = 2127.  There are 12 bits starting 20 from the left which are 0111 1110 0001 = 2017, but these are not at the expected offset.

Comment: Why code `unsigned long long int code : 26;` instead of `unsigned  int code : 26;`?  Do you have 16-bit `unsigned` concerns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The layout of bitfields within a `struct` and any padding that may exist between them is implementation defined.

From section 6.7.2.1 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> *11* An implementation may allocate any addressable storage unit large enough to hold a bit- field.  If enough space remains, a bit-field
>   that immediately follows another bit-field in a structure shall be
>   packed into adjacent bits of the same unit.  If insufficient space
>   remains, whether  a  bit-field  that  does  not  fit  is  put  into 
>   the  next  unit  or  overlaps  adjacent  units  is
>   implementation-defined.  The order of allocation of bit-fields within
>   a unit (high-order to low-order  or  low-order  to  high-order)  is 
>   implementation-defined.  The  alignment  of  the addressable storage
>   unit is unspecified.

This means that you can't rely on the layout in a standard-compliant manner.

That being said, lets take a look at how the bits are being laid out in this particular case.  To reiterate, **everything from here down is in the realm of implementation defined behavior**.  We'll start with the second case where `m2.datablob` is 8662973939721 as that is easier to explain.

First let's look at the bit representation of the values you assign to `m2`:

```
 - hour:       9:   0 1001 (0x09)
 - minutes:    0:   00 0000 (0x00)
 - seconds:    0:   00 0000 (0x00)
 - day:       30:   11 1110 (0x3E)
 - month:      5:   0101 (0x05)
 - year:    2017:   0111 1110 0001 (0x7e1)
 - code: 4195376:   00 0100 0000 0000 0100 0011 0000 (0x0400430)
```

Now let's look at the blob values, first `m` which assigns to `blobvalue` then `m2` which assigns to each field individually with the above values:

```
131809282883593  0x77E13D7C0009                        0111 0111 1110 0001 
                                   0011 1101 0111 1100 0000 0000 0000 1001

  8662973939721  0x07E1017C0009                        0000 0111 1110 0001 
                                   0000 0001 0111 1100 0000 0000 0000 1001
```

If we start by looking at the values from the right going left, we can see the value 9, so there's our first 5 bits.  Next is two sets of 6 zero bits for the next two fields.  After that, we see the bit patterns for 30, then 5.
A little further up we see the bit pattern for the value 2017, but there are 6 bits set to zero between this value and the prior ones.  So it looks like the layout is as follows:

```
          year        ???  month  day   sec     min  hour
      ------------   -----  ---  ----  ------  ----- -----
     |            | |     ||   ||    ||      ||     |     |
0000 0111 1110 0001 0000 0001 0111 1100 0000 0000 0000 1001
```

So there's some padding between the `year` and `month` fields.  Comparing the `m` and `m2` representations, the differences are in the 6 bits of padding between `month` and `year` as well as 4 bits to the left of `year`.

What we don't see here are the bits for the `code` field.  So just how big is the struct?

If we add this to the code:

```
printf("size = %zu\n", sizeof(struct Message));
```

We get:

```
size = 16
```

It's considerable bigger than we thought.  So let's make the `bytes` array `unsigned char [16]` and output it.  The code:

```
int i;
printf("m: ");
for (i=0; i<16; i++) {
    printf(" %02x", m.bytes[i]);
}
printf("\n");
printf("m2:");
for (i=0; i<16; i++) {
    printf(" %02x", m2.bytes[i]);
}
printf("\n");
```

Output:

```
m:  09 00 7c 3d e1 77 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
m2: 09 00 7c 01 e1 07 00 00 30 04 40 00 00 00 00 00
```

Now we see the 0x0400430 bit pattern corresponding to the code field in the representation for m2.  There are an additional 20 bits of padding before this field.  Also note that the bytes are in the reverse order of the value which tells us we're on a little-endian machine.  Given the way the values are laid out, it's also likely that the bits within each byte are also little-endian.

So why the padding?  It's most likely related to alignment.  The first 5 fields are 8 bits or less, meaning they each fit into a byte.  There is no alignment requirement for single bytes, so they are packed.  The next field is 12 bits, meaning it needs to fit into a 16 bit (2 byte) field.  So 6 bits of padding are added so this field starts on a 2 byte offset.  The next field is 26 bits, which needs a 32 bit field.  This would mean it needs to start on a 4 byte offset and use 4 bytes, however since this field is declared `unsigned long long`, which in this case is 8 bytes, the field uses up 8 bytes.  Had you declared this field `unsigned int` it would probably still start on the same offset but only use up 4 more bytes instead of 8.

Now what about the first case where the blob value is 131810088189961?  Let's look at its representation compared to the "expected" one:

```
131809282883593  0x77E13D7C0009                        0111 0111 1110 0001 
                                   0011 1101 0111 1100 0000 0000 0000 1001

131810088189961  0x77E16D7C0009                        0111 0111 1110 0001 
                                   0110 1101 0111 1100 0000 0000 0000 1001
```

These two representations have the same values in the bits that store the data.  The difference between them is in the 6 padding bits between the `month` and `year` fields.  As to why this representation is different, the compiler probably made some optimizations when it realized certain bits weren't or couldn't be read or written.  By adding a `char` array to the union, it because possible that those bits could be read or written so that optimization could no longer be made.

With gcc, you could try using `__attribute((packed))` on the struct.  Doing that gives the following output (after adjusting the `bytes` array to 8 along with the loop limits when printing):

```
size = 8
9:0:0 30.5.2127 code:479
m2.datablob: should: 131809282883593 is: 1153216309106573321
m.datablob:  should: 131809282883593 is: 131809282883593
9:0:0 30.5.2017 code:4195376
m:  09 00 7c 3d e1 77 00 00
m2: 09 00 7c 85 1f 0c 01 10
```

And the bit representation:

```
1153216309106573321 0x10010C1F857C0009   0001 0000 0000 0001 0000 1100 0001 1111
                                         1000 0101 0111 1100 0000 0000 0000 1001

    131810088189961 0x77E16D7C0009       0000 0000 0000 0000 0111 0111 1110 0001 
                                         0110 1101 0111 1100 0000 0000 0000 1001
```

But even with this, [you could run into issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8568432/is-gccs-attribute-packed-pragma-pack-unsafe).

So to summarize, with bitfields there's no guarantee of the layout.  You're better off using bit shifting and masking to get the values in and out of the bitfields rather than attempting to overlay it.

Comment: thank you for that very detailed answer, @dbush i aprreciate it very much. I tried to replicate this on another machine and got slightly different results, which was pretty enlightening.  

Now i know why not to use bitfields - and 'unsigned' if, possible.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here lies in line 37 where you do:

```
m2.elems.code = 4195376;
```

You assigned a invalid type to your bit field:

```
struct Message {
     unsigned int hour : 5;
     unsigned int minutes : 6;
     unsigned int seconds : 6;
     unsigned int day : 5;
     unsigned int month : 4;
     unsigned int year : 12;
     unsigned long long int code : 26; <-- invalid
};
```

see: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_bit_fields.htm
in the Topic: **Bit Field Declaration**

There it says you can only use **int**, **signed int** and **unsigned int** as Type.

**I think the Compiler interpretes m2.elems.code as int and i don't know what he exactly does with an assignment greater than max int**.

Answer (score 1):

To reiterate, the layout of bits within bit-field structs is not guaranteed (i.e. it is compiler dependent) and so this kind of bit manipulation is not good practice. To achieve such functionality bit manipulation should be used instead.

A quick example of this might be:

```
#define HOUR_BIT_START 59 // The bit number where hour bits starts
#define HOUR_BIT_MASK 0x1F // Mask of 5 bits for the hour bits

unsigned int getHour(long long int blob)
{
    return (unsigned int)((blob >> HOUR_BIT_START) & HOUR_BIT_MASK);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    unsigned long long int datablob = 131809282883593;

    printf("%d:%d:%d %d.%d.%d code:%lu\n", getHour(datablob), getMinutes(datablob), getSeconds(datablob), getDay(datablob), getMonth(datablob), getyear(datablob), getCode(datablob)); 
}
```

I'll leave the implementation of the other `get*()` functions to you