# In c, how is uint8_t structure_member[4] different than uint32_t structure_member in regards to structure padding?

Tags: c, struct, padding

FYI: This is my first question using stackoverflow!

The code is as follows:

```
uint8_t TestVar1;
uint8_t TestVar2;


typedef struct
{
  uint8_t member1;
  uint32_t member2;
}Test1;

typedef struct
{
  uint8_t member1;
  uint8_t member2[4];
}Test2;

Test1 TestStruct1; 
Test2 TestStruct2; 

TestVar1 = sizeof(TestStruct1); /*size is 8*/
TestVar2 = sizeof(TestStruct2); /*size is 5*/
```

I thought I understood padding but I can't explain TestVar2. I can explain TestVar1 being 8 bytes because there is 3 padding bytes as part of uint8_t member1.

However, with struct test2 are there no padding bytes? (Apparently not) Could someone provide some insight as to what is happening in struct test2 case?

As a side note, I am aiming for 5 bytes but I don't know why the second case works. Is the array breaking down to a pointer or something? Is this safe(standard practice) to do?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no standard requirement for a specific padding. But in this case it can be related to the fact that `uint32_t` has to be 4-bytes aligned to work efficiently (or work at all)

Comment: There's no need to pad the struct with the `uint8_t[4]` as it is made up of a bunch of one-byte types that require no special alignment for efficiency.

Comment: Really no guarantee, Test1 might be 8 bytes, Test2 too, but with padding of member1 in Test1 and padding at the end in Test2. Also the byte order in a uint32_t might be little endian or big endian (or even other exotic byte orders).

Comment: @ChristianGibbons with uint8_t[4] what does the memory look like for the structure? When accessing the 4 byte array, would you just typecast the array to a uint32_t*? or simply memcpy it to a 32 bit integer? In other words, in general,  why would I bother using a 32 bit integer as a structure member as opposed to using byte arrays? The application is for a communication protocol. Seems like I can simply "sizeof" the structure and send it out the door. (out the door means transmit the data lol)

Comment: I suspected communication might be coming into play with the concern over padding.  I believe typecasting the `uint8_t` array to `uint32_t *` would be a violation of C's strict aliasing and therefore be undefined behavior.  I believe the best choice would be to go the `__attribute__((packed))` route to remove the padding.  And I would also put the `uint32_t` member at the start of the struct so that it will be 4-byte aligned.  So something like this: `typedef struct __attribute__((packed)) { uint32_t member2; uint8_t member1; }test;`

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Yes I see your point about typecasting. Is there any adverse behavior with memcpy'ing the data? And yes, I could change the ordering but that doesn't satisfy the specific communication protocol that I am supporting. With this in mind I was thinking of just memcpy'ing.

Comment: I do not believe there is a specific issue with using `memcpy` to move data into a byte-array.  I would be curious as to the difference in efficiency between using that and just assigning to the unaligned `uint32_t` were you to use `__attribute__((packed))` without reordering the members.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons I believe some architectures does not support unaligned access in a structure. It is my understanding some do (with a time penalty) while others do not support it whatsoever.

Comment: It seems you are correct on that matter.  SPARC, specifically, will give a bus error trying to access misaligned variables. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8568441/8513665

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`uint8_t` has no specific alignment requirements and thus does not require any padding to align it while `uint32_t`, being a multi-byte type, will want to be aligned on a 4-byte boundary.  If you absolutely must have a struct with a `uint8_t` and `uint32_t` that takes only 5 bytes, you can use `__attribute__((packed))` to tell the compiler to forego the padding (which I would carefully consider whether the space saved is worth misalignment):

```
typedef struct __attribute__((packed)) {
    uint8_t member1;
    uint32_t member2;
}test;
```

Another thing to consider is the ordering of the struct members.  To keep a reduced struct size, put the largest members at the beginning of the struct as they will have the strictest alignment needs.  Consider the following:

```
typedef struct {
    uint8_t w;
    uint32_t x;
    uint8_t y;
    uint32_t z;
}test2;

typedef struct {
    uint32_t x;
    uint32_t z;
    uint8_t w;
    uint8_t y;
}test3;
```

In order to keep the `uint32_t` members aligned, `test2` will put padding after `w` and `y`, while `test3` will already have the `uint32_t` members aligned and only put enough padding at the end of the struct so that the next free memory segment aligns with a 4-bytes boundary (as that is the strictest boundary of any of the struct's members).  Therefore `test2` will have a size of 16 bytes while `test3` will have a size of 12 bytes.

Note: I have not seen where, if at all, this is defined in the C specs, but the results hold true for both gcc and clang in my tests.