# Store UDP packet in Structure using C++

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, structure, packet

I am new in `C++` programming. I am trying to create a Software which communicates to `Camera`. I am able to communicate `Camera` to my `Software`.
Through WireShark I can see that camera is sending me `packet` which is `hex representation`.

I want to store that packets in structure.

For Example:-

The packet I get is

```
 char packet_bytes[] = {
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x10, 
};
```

each value is of `1 byte`
I want to store the exact value in this `struct`

**My Code to store in Struct**

```
m_receivedBytes = recvfrom(sock, (char*)m_packetBuffer, sizeof(m_packetBuffer), 0, (sockaddr*)&cameraInfo, &m_socketLength);
        if (m_receivedBytes > 0)
        {

            switch (m_protocolType)
            {
            case StreamProtocol: ProtocolStruct.m_status = m_packetBuffer[0] + m_packetBuffer[1];
                            ProtocolStruct.m_blockID = m_packetBuffer[2] + m_packetBuffer[3];
                            ProtocolStruct.m_format = m_packetBuffer[4];
                            ProtocolStruct.m_packetID = m_packetBuffer[5] + m_packetBuffer[6] + m_packetBuffer[7];

                            switch (ProtocolStruct.m_format)
                            {
                            case 1: ProtocolStruct.m_leader->m_fieldInfo = m_packetBuffer[9];
                                    ProtocolStruct.m_leader->m_payloadType = m_packetBuffer[10] + m_packetBuffer[11];
                                    break;
                            default:
                                break;
                            }
                            break;

            default:        
                        break;
            }
```

The packet size is 22 so I store the value like this, I know this is wrong.

**Example**

If the 2 bytes are `10 01` the when I use `+` operator then result is `11` which is incorrect The correct answer should be `1001`.

So can anyone please tell me how to put all that data in Structure

Comment: Sir if I use  (|, &, <<, >>) then can I get get (1001)?

Comment: The addition is correct – 10 + 1 = 11 regardless of your numerical base – but addition is not what you're looking for. Read about bitwise operations and shifting ( `|`, `&`, `>>`, `<<`).

Comment: You can generally reassemble things by bit-shifting left (`<<`) and bitwise-ORing (`|`) - e.g. `x = (buf[n] << 24)  |  (buf[n+1] << 16) | (buf[n+2] << 8) | buf[n+3]` - but you need to make sure `m_packetBuffer` is an array of `unsigned char` / `uint8_t`.  Alternatively, you could aim e.g. `uint32_t* p = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(&m_packetBuffer[n])` then read `*p` (in which case leave `m_packetBuffer` as an array of `char`).  Either way, you may need to convert for [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) - see [`htonl`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/htonl) et al.

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with telecoms packets, you have to insure that the same exact byte layout and order is shared between the two peers. 
You problem is that a struct definition is compiler specific ; one quick and dirty way is to use a "packed" layout :

```
struct __attribute__((__packed__)) ProtocolStruct
{
    __int16         m_status;
    __int16         m_blockID;
    __int8          m_format;
    __int32         m_packetID;
    struct Trailer *m_trailer;

}ProtocolStruct;
```

This solve the layout problem but not the byte order problem also name endianess.

However not always enough see [Is gcc's __attribute__((packed)) / #pragma pack unsafe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8568432/is-gccs-attribute-packed-pragma-pack-unsafe)